# Is there a way to have a reference to an instance, with a seperate __repr__ method?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a tool that finds nested attributes within a class and saves the path. The problem is that lots of these classes have VERY long `__repr__` methods defined, which makes it unfeasible for display. I am looking to create somekind of reference to this class which is displayed as something like:

```py
<Class ref Random_module.Random_class>
```

for example:

```py
reference = RefrenceClass(AlreadyExistsClass)
print(reference)
#  <Class ref Random_module.AlreadyExistsClass>
```

I am not to sure how I could go about this. I have seen on other questions that you can **not** change the `__repr__` of an instance after the class is created. I am wondering if there is anyway to simulate this effect, potentially with a constructor of sorts? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you need to change the repr and not just display whatever text you want?

Comment: Because the item needs to be a reference to the class. Lets say it is item 3 in a list. I need to be able to say list_of_attrs[2].whatever_attribute. I am hoping there is a way to do that. It should be custom text, but callable. And when called needs to map to the instance.